# How to implement composite keys using Sugar ORM

Tags: android, composite-primary-key, sugarorm

Does anyone know how to work with composite keys in Sugar ORM?

I have some tables that have composite keys, with 3 or more columns.

Is there any @annotation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, in my research this feature is not implemented in SugarORM.
I gave up on using SugarORM and started using SQLite natively on Android.
It was much faster to implement and much more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

uniqueCombo can be used to have the database insure that *all* of the columns marked with this as true will together be unique.

@DatabaseField (uniqueCombo = true)

http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html#uniqueCombo()

Comment: ORMLite and SugarORM are different ORM systems.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my research, this feature is not working in SugarORM.